# Deep Linking to user profile in facebook iOS App post Graph API v2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to deep link to user profile in facebook iOS app from my app. For that I need to open the url fb://profile/{profile-id}. However, graph api V2.0 doesn't return the user's original id. I just get the app-scoped-id. Because of this, I'm not able to link to the user profile.
Any idea how to get the profile-id or is there any alternate way to deeplink to the user's (not just the logged in user) profile in the facebook app?

Comment: I've just run into this as well. Strangely the app scoped id works for loading the user's profile in a browser, but not through the native app schema url. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I asked facebook developers and opened a bug but their official reply is that it is not supported at this moment. See https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/738578982852285/?qa_ref=qd & https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1440071379594553/

Comment: As a weaker alternative, you can deeplink to Facebook website. But don't use http://www.facebook.com/{profile_id} since it'll matches an url scheme of the FB native app and open the link in the native app. You can use http://www.facebook.org/{profile_id} instead.